# How to avoid inject warning in beforeEach?

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I use Pinia in a Quasar project.

When the code is according the doc from pinia, it creates a warning:

```
import {useAuthStore} from "stores/auth-store";
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter()

const beforeEach = ((to, from, next) => {

  const store = useAuthStore()

  if (to.meta.needsAuth) {

    if (store.authenticated) {
      next()
    }
    else {
      router.push('/')
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
  
})

export default beforeEach
```

Warning:

```
[Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.
```

I followed the doc from Pinia:
https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html#single-page-applications

If I set  `const store = useAuthStore()` before the  `const store = useAuthStore()` there is an error.

How do I have to modify the code to avoid the warning?

Comment: I would simply use `reactive()` instead of Pinia or Vuex.